# Flex: How to apply CSS to ActionScript Componet?

Tags: css, apache-flex

I have a Flex ActionScript component. How can I apply CSS to this component? I'm hoping to be able to apply styles from an external CSS file.

CSS Selector in file 'global.css':

```
.myPanel
{
color:#cccccc;
background-color:#333333;
border-color:#ff0000;
border-style:solid;
}
```

My Flex component:

```
package components
{
import mx.containers.Panel;

public class myPanel extends Panel
{
public function myPanel()
{
   super();
}

override protected function createChildren():void
{
super.createChildren();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if your component is defined via Actionscript, you'll have to manually define your css styles within the constructor or init function (e.g.):

```
//create and initialize css
var myCSS:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
myCSS.setStyle("body", {fontSize:'15',color:'#000066'});
myCSS.setStyle("h1", {fontSize:'25',color:'#000000'});
myCSS.setStyle("h2", {fontSize:'19',color:'#000000'});
myCSS.setStyle("a:link", {color:'#0000CC',textDecoration:'none'});
myCSS.setStyle("a:hover", {color:'#0000FF',textDecoration:'underline'});
myCSS.setStyle("b", {fontWeight:'bold'});
myCSS.setStyle("em", {fontWeight:'bold'});
```

An easier way would be to define your component as an mxml component and define the stylesheet in the header, like so:

```
<fx:Style source="../assets/css/global.css"/>
```

And your css file:

Answer (score 0):

You can add style to your element:

```
this.setStyle('styleName', 'myPanel');
```

(not sure about this, need to be checked, but if you have element it will work) In this case selector

```
.myPanel
```

will work

To load css file use:

```
<fx:Style source="qx.css"/>
```

in you mxml file